# Programatically put textview on imageview Android

Tags: android, bitmap, textview, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I'm trying to put text on imageview, but I don't know how to do that programmatically.
first, I download an image from firebase storage, and then I want to put this image in a linearlayout with some text on it. This process repeats itself to the number of times as there are images at the database.

This is my code:
XML:

```
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

and the relevant code from the activity:

```
                    fileRef.getFile(localFile)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                    LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
                                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(finalLocalFile.getAbsolutePath());
                                    TextView textView = new TextView(GaleryActivity.this);
                                    textView.setText("Something");
                                    textView.setTextSize(24);
                                    Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "aqua.ttf");
                                    textView.setTypeface(typeFace);
                                    textView.setGravity(Gravity.END|Gravity.BOTTOM);
                                    linearLayout.addView(textView);
                                    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                                    imageView.setBackground(GaleryActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mybutton));
                                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                    linearLayout.addView(imageView,params);
```

Comment: why you just don't use the recycler view and handle it in recycler item model XML?

Comment: I will try this, thank you

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout arranges Views one by one, views cannot be overlayed. You can use FrameLayout to overlap TextView on top of ImageView. Or you can use RecyclerView if you have list of many items.